# How do I write this method in Scala, or what is the best way to deal with early returns

Tags: scala

Playing around with a bit of Scala, and it seems like you can't return early from a function.

I find flat unindented code with early returns easy to follow. My initial attempts created a big nested structure. Call me picky but I don't like seeing the following:

```
    }
  }
}
```

What is the best way to write the following method in Scala?

Is it possible to program in such a way to reduce nesting, or would I be fighting against the functional design philosophy of Scala the whole way?

```
@Nullable
public static <T extends PsiElement> T getParentOfType(@Nullable PsiElement element,
                                                       @NotNull Class<T> aClass,
                                                       boolean strict,
                                                       @NotNull Class<? extends PsiElement>... stopAt) {
  if (element == null) return null;
  if (strict) {
    element = element.getParent();
  }

  while (element != null && !aClass.isInstance(element)) {
    if (instanceOf(element, stopAt)) return null;
    if (element instanceof PsiFile) return null;
    element = element.getParent();
  }

  //noinspection unchecked
  return (T)element;
}
```

My attempt:

```
def getParentOfType[T](element: PsiElement, aClass: Class, strict: Boolean): T[_ <: PsiElement] = {
  element match {
    case null => null
    case _ => {
      var el = if (strict) {
        element.getParent
      } else element
      while(el != null) {
        if (aClass isInstance el) {
          return el
        }
        if (el.isInstanceOf[PsiFile]) return null;
        el = el.getParent()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, what is the appropriate forum in the Scala-world to ask "What is the best way to write Java method X in Scala?". I find myself asking this question a lot.

Comment: Please show your attempt to write this method in Scala.

Comment: I don't like seeing superfluous braces, but you're using them in your example... Anyway, Scala has `return`, though it is not a precise replacement for that in Java. The real answer is that good Scala code looks different than good Java code and some adjustment is necessary. All in all, decent Scala code is much more concise than corresponding Java code, even if idiomatic Scala strongly discourages use of `return`.

Comment: @senia Added my impl.

Comment: You never need braces around the code of a `case ... =>` clause in Scala. Nor any single-expression body of a method, `if` / `else`, etc. Try to cut the noise-inducing superfluous punctuation out of your Scala code (Java, too, though it's less risky to do so in Scala).

Answer (score 5):

```
def getParentOfType[T](element: PsiElement, aClass: Class, strict: Boolean):
    T[_ <: PsiElement] = element match {
  case null => null
  case el if strict => getParentOfType(el.getParent, aClass, false)
  case el if aClass isInstance el => el
  case el if el.isInstanceOf[PsiFile] => null
  case el => getParentOfType(el.getParent, aClass, false)
}
```

(or similar)

Comment: The pattern matching does make the cases easier to read.  Unfortunately you suggestion doesn't handle the `while` loop (e.g. the second case isn't correct, as `el.getParent` goes through the loop rather than being immediately returned.)

Comment: Very easy to read, but `case el if strict => el.getParent` returns without going through loop.

Comment: Looks good, thanks. Like how flat the code is and easy to follow. Not that DRY tho with the repetition of `el` and `getParentOfType`, but then I'm just being picky.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to use scala with `null`. And you can't get idiomatic scala code with `while`.

You have `@Nullable` and `@NotNull` - in scala it is `Option[T]` and `T`. You could replace `while` with recursive method.

For instance this is my attempt to translate your method to scala (not tested):

```
getParentOfType[T <: PsiElement](element: Option[PsiElement],
                                 aClass: Class[T],
                                 strict: Boolean,
                                 stopAt: Class[_ <: PsiElement]*): Option[T] = element flatMap { el =>
  @tailrec def loop(element: PsiElement): Option[PsiElement] {
    if (element == null || aClass.isInstance(element))
      Option(element)
    else if (instanceOf(element, stopAt) || element.isInstanceOf[PsiFile])
      None
    else
      loop(element.getParent())
  }

  loop(if (strict) el.getParent() else el).map{_.asInstanceOf[T]}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different take on the problem; probably not what I'd use in this particular case but it's worth knowing about.

```
def getParentOfType[A >: Null <: PsiElement](
  element: PsiElement, aClass: Class[A],
  strict: Boolean, stopAt: Class[_ <: PsiElement]*
): A =
  Iterator.iterate(element)(_.getParent).
  takeWhile(_ != null).
  drop(if (strict) 1 else 0).
  takeWhile(e => !instanceOf(e, stopAt) && !e.isInstanceOf[PsiFile]).
  collectFirst{ case x if aClass isInstance x => x.asInstanceOf[A] }.
  orNull
```

Here, you start by defining the stream of parents of your element, which terminates if it's null.  You drop the first one if your strict flag is true; you also stop searching if you hit something in `stopAt` or a `PsiFile`.  Within those constraints, you get (and cast) the first thing that matches, and then you return that or null if you didn't get anything.

With a bit of practice it can actually be *easier* to follow this kind of logic than the looping since the termination conditions are more implicit in the loop than here.  Here you just state flat out when you stop searching (`takeWhile`) and what you're after (`collectFirst`).

Note: I am assuming `instanceOf` is defined as

```
def instanceOf(a: AnyRef, cs: Seq[Class[_]]) = cs.exists(_ isInstance a)
```

Comment: On first read I couldn't follow this (Scala beginner). But after reading your explanation it appears a really nice way to reason about it, and I like the aesthetic style of the code too.

Comment: `probably not what I'd use in this particular case but it's worth knowing about.` Why is that, and what would you use in this case?

Comment: @vaughan - The tail-recursive pattern match is more straightforward in this case.  I'd probably use that instead.  If I were doing more things that were hard to do manually and easy to do with collections (e.g. if there was a filter step) then I'd switch to this approach.